# Div not having a top postion of 0%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with multiple child divs inside that are spaced around to fit the main div. The middle child div has multiple divs inside it that contain different data. I have separated the divs inside the middle div into a left and a right part of the middle div now the left side is aligned properly to fit the middle div with the proper top positioning and height but the right div is not having a 0% top positioning and not having a height of 100%. To make it easier to identify, the right div is the one that has inner html of `USD 900`. I want it to have a top of 0% and a height of 100%. How can I achieve that? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
.shelf2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

.shelf2 .level1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .topLeftLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .topLeftLevel2Items p {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .bottomLeftLevel2Items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  background-color: green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .bottomLeftLevel2Items p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 85%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="shelf2">
  <div class="level1">

  </div>
  <div class="level2">
    <div class="leftLevel2Items">
      <div class="topLeftLevel2Items">
        <p>I.PHONE 11 PRO MAX 256GB COMPLETE BOX WITH ALL ACCESSORIES FOR SALE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomLeftLevel2Items">
        <p>Posted 1 day ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightLevel2Items">
      <P>USD 900</P>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the desired result... The `div` with "USD 900" has a background-color of pink ~ but something tells me you want "USD 900" in the orange space... If not, does that mean you want the "USD 900" with the pink background-color to be the full height with text on top like this?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjGoa.png

Comment: but the height should be 100% of the middle div not the whole main div @ カメロン

Comment: basically the pink should replace the orange part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `left: 85%;` from `.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items`. Then set `display: flex;` with `align-items: baseline;` on `.level2`.

In my personal opinion, I think you could achieve the desired result by not using so much `flex`. Flex is great but it works best when you use it only on the items that need it.

You can regain your pink background color if you remove the `absolute` positioning on `.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items p`. If you go that route, I would use `align-items: center;` instead of baseline.

```css
.shelf2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #87CEEB;
}

.shelf2 .level1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .topLeftLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .topLeftLevel2Items p {
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .bottomLeftLevel2Items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  background-color: green;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .leftLevel2Items .bottomLeftLevel2Items p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.shelf2 .level2 .rightLevel2Items p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.shelf2 .level3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid green;
}

.level2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="shelf2">
  <div class="level1">

  </div>
  <div class="level2">
    <div class="leftLevel2Items">
      <div class="topLeftLevel2Items">
        <p>I.PHONE 11 PRO MAX 256GB COMPLETE BOX WITH ALL ACCESSORIES FOR SALE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomLeftLevel2Items">
        <p>Posted 1 day ago</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightLevel2Items">
      <P>USD 900</P>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="level3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.

Comment: @seriously no problem!